# How does the excess GPE of a mountain cause its base to melt?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, earth, geophysics

Weisskopf suggested that the Gravitational Potential Energy (GPE) of a vertical column of mountain rock of mass $m$ must be less than the latent heat of fusion $L_f$ of the rock, i.e. $$mgh<η L_fm   $$

η is a dimensionless constant

He coined this concept by solely considering the energy balance in which excess GPE will always be transformed into energy to melt the base of such a column of rock. However, does there exist a physical explanation of how this occurs, not just one based on the conservation of energy (although it is always true)?

In addition, the $h$ used in the GPE is the total height of the column. Should it not be $h$/2 instead (assuming uniform distribution of mass), considering the GPE of such a column is dependent on the height from its base to its centre of mass, not the full height?

References:

Weisskopf, V.F., “Physics of Mountains.” American Journal of Physics 54, 871 (1986).

Faraoni, V, "Alpine Physics." World Scientific, (2019).

Comment: *Should it not be $h/2$ instead?* The fudge factor $\eta$ can take care of that.

Comment: Interesting. That suggests there should be a relationship between the yield stress and the latent heat of fusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, does there exist a physical explanation of how this occurs, not just one based on the conservation of energy

From Weisskopf's [response to comments](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/54/10/871/1045951/Physics-of-mountains-response):

> I have used the melting heat...as a measure of the energy...necessary to induce plastic flow.

In other words, viscous flow is broadly similar to melting because a fair fraction of the bonds are broken with each; we expect (and find) more [refractory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractory) materials to better resist [creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creep_(deformation)). This is why [deformation mechanism maps](https://defmech.engineering.dartmouth.edu/) are commonly plotted using the [homologous temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homologous_temperature):

[image]

Weisskopf further emphases that the broad equivalence is proposed as an order-of-magnitude comparison only.